# Using Socket IO with node js socket.to(socket.id).emit() throws error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using Socket.io in my application which need to get the response from the server and send it to the client. I can get the response but I receive this error.

[image]

What it can means? I can't find anything.

This is the Socket IO config file.

```
const logger = require("log4js").getLogger("NET_SERVER");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const redis = require("async-redis");

const SocketIO = http_server => () => {
  const io = socketio(http_server());
  io.adapter(require("socket.io-redis")({host: "localhost", port: 6379}));
  SocketIO.io = io;

  io.on("connection", connection);

  function connection(socket) {
    logger.info(`Connected to: \`${socket.id}\``);

    const sub = redis.createClient(6379);

    disconnect(socket, sub);
    join(socket, sub);
    leave(socket, sub);
    progress(socket, sub);
  }

  function disconnect(socket, sub) {
    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      logger.info(`Client disconnected \`${socket.id}\`.`);

      sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }

  function join(socket, sub) {
    socket.on("join", room => {
      logger.info(`Socket \`${socket.id}\` joining the \`${room}\` room.`);

      sub.subscribe(room);

      socket.join(room);
    });
  }

  function leave(socket, sub) {
    socket.on("leave", room => {
      logger.info(`Client live the \`${room}\` room.`);

      sub.unsubscribe(room);

      socket.leave(room);
    });
  }

  function progress(socket, sub) {
    sub.on("message", (room, progress) => {
      logger.info(
        `Sockek message room: \`${room}\`, progress: \`${progress}\`.`,
      );

      io.in(room).emit("progress", progress);
    });
  }
};

module.exports = SocketIO;
```

This is the code from which it throws this error.

```
    try {
    const SocketIO = require("../../config/socketio").io;
  
    const bodyJson = req.body;
    SocketIO.to(req.query.id).emit("onComplete", bodyJson);

    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex);
    }
```

Comment: What is `SocketIO`? You'd need to include more code, otherwise we're not sure how to help you...

Comment: You can see the edit.

Comment: I'm completely lost. The first file exports `SocketIO` **method**, which takes `http_server` as parameter. This method is **never** called - you're directly requiring the file and expecting to have `io` property. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have already solved this problem. It's regarding with io.adapter, which is blocks all emits.  In my code, I have used io.adapter for Redis.